# listbox1.items.add how to call outside the base methods?

Tags: c#, winforms

I expected that when calling ListBox2, lines would be added to ListBoxAdd() (in basic methods such as Form1 or button4_Click, everything works, but they are private, and they cannot be changed)

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
  public Form1()
    {
       InitializeComponent();
             }
             private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
             {
             }
      public void ListBoxAdd(int i, string print)
       {
               Form1 form = new Form1();
               listBox2.Items.Add(print); 
      }
       public class Exel_AllInOne : Form1
           {
      public void ListBoxExportUpdate()
       {
        form.ListBoxAdd(2, "hi");
     }
           }
          }
```

Comment: can you more explain(which do you call event listBox2)?why do you create Exel_AllInOne ?